# Android screen freezes while sending data to usb device

Tags: android, usb

I have following problem - I need to send data to my usb device and read tag of the device. First I need to turn on device - that's what table pal does. Next, when response from device equals DAAD0674016F6B26 I need to start scan - table readId. After that depends if response is DAAD046F62ADA900 - that means that in 3 sec device didn't found tag to scan and device turned off. My task is to send again command to turn it on ... and again, and again and so on (I know it's quite expensive - command every 3 sec - it wasn't my idea). But , when the response is different than DAAD046F62ADA900 - that's my tag :)To sum up - if response is DAAD046F62ADA900 I need to send command to scan again I try to do it with while loop :

```
while(shouldReceive) {
sendCommand
}
```

but the screen freezes so I tried to do it in thread , and right now it looks like this :

```
final Thread receive= new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public UsbDevice device;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            usbManager = (UsbManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
            getActivity().registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);
            shouldReceaive = true;
            HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
            Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
            while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
                final UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();

                if (device.getVendorId() == 1659 && device.getProductId() == 8963) {
                    this.device = device;
                    usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
                    break;
                }
            }
            final UsbConnector.CallbackListener listener = new UsbConnector.CallbackListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(UsbConnector.Status newStatus) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Status" + newStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String result) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Result" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
            shouldReceaive = true;

                UsbConnector connector = new UsbConnector(getContext(), device, listener);
                connector.run();
                connector.send(pal);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                byte[] received = connector.receive(36);
                if (received == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Błąd inicjalizacji skanera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (received != null) {
                    String response = null;
                    long longValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(received).getLong();
                    response = Long.toHexString(longValue).toUpperCase();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "RESPONSE: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (response.contentEquals("DAAD0674016F6B26")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Rozpoczynam skanowanie ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        connector.send(readId);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        byte[] receivedTag = connector.receive(36);
                        if (receivedTag != null) {
                            String tag = null;
                            long tagValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(receivedTag).getLong();
                            tag = Long.toHexString(tagValue).toUpperCase();
                            while (tag.contentEquals("DAAD046F62ADA900")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "PING, SKANUJE DALEJ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                connector.send(readId);
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                                String tag2 = null;
                                long tagValue2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(receivedTag).getLong();
                                tag2 = Long.toHexString(tagValue2).toUpperCase();
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ZESKANOWANY TAG!: " + tag2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                for (Car cary : carList) {
                                    if (tag2.contentEquals(cary.getmNumber())) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "setCars: JEST");
                                    } else {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "setCars: NIE MA");
                                    }
                                }

                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Błąd przy inicjalziacji skanera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            }

    });
    mScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            receive.run();

        }
    });
```

but problem still exists. Screen freezes and user can do nothing. Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: have you tried asyncTast?

Comment: No, only new thread

Comment: Try to use asyncTast, but I'm not sure if it helps. Also, try to divide you code into pieces by putting logcat between the lines. Then find the cause of the issue. Your code is to big to read.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke run() method, it's executed on the calling thread (in your case on **UI thread**).

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         receive.run();
    }
```

**Try this:**

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        receive.start();
    }
```

Comment: App crashes in that case. The main problem is, that I've got usb device plugged so I can't even check logs to find issue. It's really annoying.